# Passing epoch time as date in API post request

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails-5

I am making an API Post request in my Rails 5 application with HTTParty as

```
emp_response = HTTParty.post("url", :body => { :AuthToken => token, :EmpIdList => ['123'],:StartDate =>'/Date(92814960000)/', :EndDate => '/Date(1565150400000)/'}.to_json,:headers => { 'Content-Type' => 'application/json' } )
```

This works if I hard code the start and end dates.

But I want to pass the current Unix Epochtime in the Start and EndDate.

I am getting the current time by doing: 
current_date = (Time.current.to_f * 1000).to_i

I want to pass this current_date in the API json Post request

When I do

```
some_var = HTTParty.post("url", :body => { :AuthToken => token, :EmpIdList => ['Y16646'],:StartDate =>'/Date(92814960000)/', :EndDate => '/Date(current_date)/'}.to_json,:headers => { 'Content-Type' => 'application/json' } )
```

I get the error: `HTTPBadRequest 400 Bad Request`.

How can I pass a variable value in  EndDate instead of hard coding it